# Obtaining output variables from Python function

Tags: python, scipy

I'm working with a function, `scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs`, which has several output variables. I care about two of them, xopt and fopt. How do I store these variables? The following isn't working for me:

```
xopt, fopt = fmin_bfgs(f, 0, fprime = fprime)
```

However, this gives me `fopt`:

```
fopt = fmin_bfgs(f, 0, fprime = fprime)
```

I need `xopt` too, but it says that I "need 1 more value to unpack."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `full_output` to true, after which `fopt`, `func_calls`, `grad_calls`, and `warnflag` are included too; you can slice the returned sequence:

```
xopt, fopt = fmin_bfgs(f, 0, fprime = fprime, full_output=True)[:2]
```

See the [`scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs.html):

> `full_output` : *bool, optional*
>   If True,return fopt, func_calls, grad_calls, and warnflag in addition to xopt.

Granted, the documentation for this function makes this far from obvious, I first had to look at the [linked source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.0/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L710). By the looks of it, `bopt` and `gopt` are also included when `full_output` is set, but the documentation fails to properly explain this.